# Prove equality of composition

Tags: functions

I have to prove or disprove $f∘f^{-1}=f^{-1}∘f\ (f:A\to B$ and $f$ is a bijective function$)$.

I get $f∘f^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}∘f$ are both identity functions. But is this fact make them equal?

Here is what I think.
$a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with  $f(a)=b$
$$f∘f^{-1}(b) = f(a)=b$$
$$f^{-1}∘f(a) = f^{-1}(b)=a$$

So if $a \not= b$ we can not say $f∘f^{-1}=f^{-1}∘f$.

I am really confused with this question. Please give me a help.

Comment: You have already asked 5 questions, it's time to learn some basic mathjax. You may consider this  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: sorry and thanks for editing

Answer (score 1):

Your proof (in your original post) has the right idea. And if you distill that idea from your work, then you don't even need all that work… Let me explain.

One thing you need to understand here is that for any set $X$ there's a unique identity function $\operatorname{Id}_X:X\to X$ on this set. But such identity functions for two different sets — say, $\operatorname{Id}_X:X\to X$ and $\operatorname{Id}_Y:Y\to Y$, where $X\neq Y$ — are by definition different functions, since their domains and codomains are different.

That's all you need here. You're right in your proof: generally speaking, $a\neq b$, and so in general $f\circ f^{-1}\neq f^{-1}\circ f$. More specifically, this conclusion is only valid if $A\neq B$ are two distinct sets. In this case, given a bijective function $f:A\to B$, the two compositions are two different identity functions. To see that, note that $f^{-1}:B\to A$. And now answer the following questions:

- What are the domain and codomain of $f^{-1}\circ f$? And therefore, which identity function is it?
- What are the domain and codomain of $f\circ f^{-1}$? And therefore, which identity function is it?

On the other hand, if $f$ is a bijection from a set $A$ to itself, $f:A\to A$, then the two compositions are equal: $f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f=\operatorname{Id}_A$.